# Searching throught ordered dictionaries

Tags: python, csv, oop, dictionary

I have made a program that reads from a csv file, with this code;

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open('FakeNameSet.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig'))
customer_list = []
for line in reader:
    customer_list.append(line)
```

This code creates these types of ordered dictionaries from my csv file;

```
OrderedDict([('Number', '19'),
              ('Gender', 'female'),
              ('NameSet', 'Dutch'),
              ('GivenName', 'Özgül'),
              ('Surname', 'Overgaauw'),
              ('StreetAddress', 'Adriana Noorlandersingel 200'),
              ('ZipCode', '3065 HE'),
              ('City', 'Rotterdam'),
              ('EmailAddress', 'OzgulOvergaauw@superrito.com'),
              ('Username', 'Shrothem1971'),
              ('TelephoneNumber', '06-15253488')]),
 OrderedDict([('Number', '20'),
              ('Gender', 'female'),
              ('NameSet', 'Dutch'),
              ('GivenName', 'Gülseren'),
              ('Surname', 'Willigenburg'),
              ('StreetAddress', 'Dingspelstraat 28'),
              ('ZipCode', '9461 JE'),
              ('City', 'Gieten'),
              ('EmailAddress', 'GulserenWilligenburg@teleworm.us'),
              ('Username', 'Ressoare'),
              ('TelephoneNumber', '06-92433659')])]
```

Now I need to access the people in this list by name, but I have no idea how to access the name in this `OrderedDict` style. I've been trying for 2 hours and nothing seems to be working.

So basically, I have a list with a number of these ordered dictionaries and I want to search for a particular person in these dictionaries; so basically a function that works as follows;

`Search_for_person("Gülseren")`, and then it returns all the information for that person.

Comment: **What** have you tried in that time though? A simple Google search for "OrderedDict access" yields exactly what you need.

Comment: I followed the instructions given here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058140/accessing-items-in-an-collections-ordereddict-by-index but what they have is not the same structure as I have right here, they make a single OrderedDict and search through that, but I have 20 of them and I just don't know what Im doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, records are ordered dictionaries but you keep customers in a list. If you only search by name, changing `customer_list` to a dictionary should solve the problem:

```
customers = {}
for line in reader:
    customers['GivenName'] = line

# assuming GivenName is unique, search customers by given name:
customer = customers["Gülseren"]
```

If you need to search by other fields, I would recommend using pandas dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

customers = pd.read_csv('FakeNameSet.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
# find customers by a given name:
# (doesn't assume uniqueness, you can get several rows)
customers[customers['GivenName] == "Gülseren"]
```