# Looping through OrderedDict objects errors

Tags: python-2.7, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to learn how to manipulate python2.7 OrderedDict objects.  I have an OrderedDict which was provided earlier in the program.  I'm trying to understand its structure and at the same time understand how to manipulate this object and extract various elements and element values from the dictionary.

In the code below I demonstrate that the initial ordered dictionary object, ***finaldata***, has one key ***['models']***.  I create a new ordered dictionary, ***fdata_models***, from ***finaldata*** using that key. And then a new ordered dictionary using one of the keys from ***fdata_models***, etc.

Below you can see my test program and the output from the its experiments.

I have several questions, but the most pressing is why I can not loop through the dictionary objects within ***fdata_models***?

After that question, I've tried the syntax "***fdata_model = fdata_models[0]***", instead of hard coding the key, ***['models']***, but that also throws an error.  Is there a way to index, say the 3-rd occurance, within ***fdata_models*** without knowing its actual key value?

```
....
fdata_models = OrderedDict()
fdata_model = OrderedDict()
fdata = OrderedDict()
print("finaldata Keys are ", finaldata.keys())
fdata_key = finaldata.keys()
print("finaldata Key is ", fdata_key)
fdata_models = finaldata['models']
print("Number of ", fdata_key, " are ", len(fdata_models))
print("['Models'] Keys are ", fdata_models.keys())    
fdata_model = fdata_models['1']
print("Number of models['1'] are ", len(fdata_model))
print(" models['1'] keys are ",fdata_model.keys())
fdata_model = fdata_models['64110']
print("Number of models['64110'] are ", len(fdata_model))
print(" models['64110'] keys are ",fdata_model.keys())
for fdata in fdata_models:
    print("fdata['model']", " keys are ", fdata[0].keys())
```

> ('finaldata Keys are ', ['models'])   ('finaldata Key is ',
>   ['models'])
>
> ('Number of ', ['models'], ' are ', 4)
>
> ("['Models'] Keys are ", ['123', '110', '111', '112'])
>
> ("Number of models['123'] are ", 7)
>
> ("models['123'] keys are ", ['model', 'Mn', 'Md', 'Opt', 'Vr', 'SN', 
>   'DA']) ("Number of models['110'] are ", 47) (" models['64110'] keys 
>   are ", ['model', 'MajorFWRev', 'MidFWRev', 'MinorFWRev', ...
>   'TimeZone', 'Date_year', 'Date_month', 'Date_Day', 'Time_hour', 
>   'Time_minute', 'Time_second', ...])    Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File  /pgms/json.py", line 204, in 
>        print("fdata['model']", " keys are ", fdata[0].keys()) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Thanks...RDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OrderedDict`s work just like `dict`s in this respect. When you iterate over them, you get the keys.

```
for fdata in fdata_models:
    print("fdata['model']", " keys are ", fdata_models[fdata].keys())
```

(Also note that all three of your `... = OrderedDict()` lines don't actually do anything useful, since you rebind `fdata_models`, `fdata_model`, and `fdata` again before you use them.)

Comment: Thanks, that works but I need to ponder over it to better understand what you did. Regatrding the three "OrderedDict" statements, I added those as I was trying figure out why my for loop was failing.

Comment: @RDK It might help you wrap your head around what's happening if you just do a `for fdata in fdata_models: print(fdata)`.

Comment: Any comments about indexing using this syntax "fdata_model = fdata_models[0]"?  I think, I've seen something like that in a couple other postings.

Comment: OK, I'll do that and based on your comments, it will list the keys?

Comment: @RDK Only if `fdata_models` has a `0` key. If you're trying to access an OrderedDict by index [there's a question for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058140/accessing-items-in-an-collections-ordereddict-by-index).