# How to get certain element from OrderedDict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, geocoding

I'm doing some reverse Geo coding to convert latitude and longitude to a location name:

```
def reverseGeocode(coordinates):
    result = rg.search(coordinates)
    print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    coord = (-33.936952777777776, 18.39005)
    reverseGeocode(coord)
```

Result has following format:

```
[OrderedDict([('lat', '-33.92584'), ('lon', '18.42322'), ('name', 'Cape Town'), ('admin1', 'Western Cape'), ('admin2', 'City of Cape Town'), ('cc', 'ZA')])]
```

How can i get to certain element of this `OrderedDict` to have just a location 'name'? That would be 'Cape Town' in this example.

Comment: In the same way you retrieve the "name" key from an ordinary dict. An OrderedDict has only a special string representation.

Comment: Or if you want by index: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058140/accessing-items-in-an-collections-ordereddict-by-index

Comment: Note that result is actually a `list` of `OrderedDict`

Comment: What is your question, exactly? If you want to know how to use a dictionary, then that's been asked before. As @MichaelButscher pointed out, you have a list of OrderedDicts, it isn't clear if you understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result[0]['name'] # == 'Cape Town'`