# Appending a key:value from one dictionary to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i want to be able to make a multiple choice quiz program using dictionaries. I have one dictionary with all the questions as the key and the answer as a value and a second dictionary thats empty. I want to append all of the incorrect questions someone may have into the empty dictionary. i want to do this in order to allow users to retake the exam but only with the questions that they answered wrong. Yet i cannot find a way to append a key and value from one list to another without being specific.

Here is my code below:

```
def intro():    
    print("Hello and welcome to the random questions test")
    global name   
    name = input("what is your name? " + "\n" + "\n")
    if name == "":
        print("Enter a valid name!")
        name = input("what is your name? " + "\n" + "\n")
    else:
        ans2 = input("\n" + "Hello " + name + " Are you sure you want to take the exam? (yes/no)"  + "\n" + "\n")
        if ans2 == "no":
            print("\n" + "aw man, until next time " + name + "!" + "\n")   
        elif ans2 == "yes":
            print("\n" + "Okay!" + "\n")
            Quiz()

def Quiz():
    q1 = """Who holds the NFL record for the most receiving yards in a single game?
        a.  Calvin Johnson
        b.  Deandre Hopkins
        c.  Flipper Anderson
        d.  Jerry Rice"""
    q2 = """In what year was the eiffel tower built?
        a.  1492
        b.  1889
        c.  2013
        d.  1766"""
    q3 = """How many countries are in the world today?
        a.  205
        b.  195
        c.  673
        d.  142"""
    q4 = """Who is the CEO of apple currently (2020)?
        a.  Tim Cook
        b.  Sergio Kitchens
        c.  Daniel Johnson
        d.  Steve Jobs"""
    q5 = """who is the 23rd president of the united states?
        a.  Grover Cleveland 
        b.  Andrew Jackson
        c.  Anderson Berkshire
        d.  Benjamin Harrison"""
    q6 = """X + 5x - 10 = 500... What does X equal?
        a.  85
        b.  84
        c.  102
        d.  0"""
    q7 = """Who is currently the richest person on earth?
        a.  Tim Cook
        b.  Jeff Bezos
        c.  Bill Gates
        d.  Bill Nye"""
    q8 = """When was Howard University Established?
        a.  May 4, 2002
        b.  March 5, 1855
        c.  September 1, 1844
        d.  March 2, 1867"""
    q9 = """What can you catch but not throw?
        a.  A football
        b.  A conversation
        c.  A cold
        d.  A tennis ball in the Appalachian Mountains"""
    q10 = """Which country is responsible for the production of 95% of the worlds opal stones?
        a.  Brazil 
        b.  Mexico
        c.  Honduras
        d.  Austrailia"""
    q11 = """How many species of Toothed and Baleen whales exist?
        a.  14 and 2
        b.  76 and 14
        c.  5 and 10
        d.  75,000"""
    q12 = """Who holds the world record for the most chicken nuggets eaten in 1 hour?
        a.  Naader Reda
        b.  Nicolo Reda
        c.  Stefano Neder
        d.  Josh Jacobs"""
    q13 = """Who invented the bessemer process?
        a.  Henry Bessemer 
        b.  Markus Bessemer
        c.  Bessemer Robinson
        d.  Anakin Skywalker"""
    q14 = """When was Mortal Kombat 6 released?
        a.  April 1, 2002
        b.  August 15, 2007
        c.  October 4, 2004
        d.  December 25, 2006"""
    q15 = """In which City located in the USA is it illegal to say "Oh, boy"?
        a.  Denver, Colorado  
        b.  Lexington, Kentucky
        c.  Jonesboro, Georgia
        d.  Wilbur, Washington"""
    Questions = {q1: 'c', q2: 'b', q3: 'b', q4: 'a', q5: 'd', q6: 'a', q7: 'b', q8: 'd', q9: 'c', q10: 'd', q11: 'b', q12: 'a', q13: 'a', q14: 'c', q15: 'c' }
    inc_questions = {}
    score = 0
    for q in Questions:
        print(q)
        ans = input("> ")
        if ans.lower() == Questions[q]:
            print("\n" + "Correct!" + "\n")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("\n" + "Incorrect!" + "\n")
            for q, a in Questions.items():
                if ans.lower() != Questions[q]:
                    inc_questions[q] = a 
   
    if score == 15: 
        print("Congratulations " + name + ", you scored a perfect 15/15!")
    elif score < 15 and score > 11:
        print("Good job " + name + "! you got " + str(score) + " out of 15 correct!")
        print("\n" + "Would you like to re-answer the questions that were incorrect?" + "\n")
    elif score < 12 and score > 8:
        print("You did pretty well " + name + ", you got " + str(score) + " out of 15 correct!")
        print("\n" + "Would you like to re-answer the questions that were incorrect?" + "\n")
    elif score < 9 and score > 5:
        print("Unfortunately " + name + " you did not pass, you got " + str(score) + " out of 15 correct!")
        print("\n" + "Would you like to re-answer the questions that were incorrect?" + "\n")
    elif score < 6 and score > 0:
        print("Jeez " + name + " you did awful lol, you got " + str(score) + " out of 15 correct!")
        print("\n" + "Would you like to re-answer the questions that were incorrect?" + "\n")
    elif score == 0:
        print("Oh lord " + name +" you need some serious help you got nothing right!")
        print("\n" + "Would you like a retake?" + "\n")
    print(inc_questions)

intro()
```

Comment: I think I would redefine your initial dictionary with keys ("q1", "q2", . . . "q15") the dictionary value can then be a tuple ("Question text", "correct answer value".  The you can cycle through the dictionary based on key, value pair.and ask ask your question with dict[key][0] and comare answer to dict[kay][1].  If answer is correct, update answer count, if answer is incorrect store the question key in a re-quiz list, so only questions with incorrect answers will be re asked.

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-dicts/

Comment: A Dictionary is a key->value pair, by definition. If you want to append you might be better off with a List. You could also use an ordered dict, if you really want to be able to "append" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058140/accessing-items-in-an-collections-ordereddict-by-index .... however, I still don't understand why you want to "append" to your dictionary - both lists and dicts are iterable.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. This is way too much code. Please make a [mre]. You can [edit] the question. Check out [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Based on my answer, the question title does not match. I am staying away from the key value pair and instead using tuples inside a list to get this working. This is more of a list solution than a dict solution. The reason for list vs. dict is to keep track of unanswered questions and iterate thru them quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem to solve. Look at this code and see if it provides you the repeatable process to keep continuing with your quiz. The only area that I have a bit of a problem is your big if statements that check for scores and print varying responses. When the user has fewer questions, I had to add the older answered questions to the tally to stay in the same range. Otherwise, this should work.

Things I changed.

#1: Questions is a list of tuples. Each tuple is a question and answer `(q1,'c')` as example.

#2: Since we need to repeat the questions, I am iterating through incorrect question list each time. To start off, I set all questions as incorrect. So the incorrect questions list has values 0 thru 14.

#3: Every time the user answers correctly, I am removing the question from the incorrect question list.

#4: Since I am manipulating the list itself by removing the correctly answered question, I cannot use a for loop. Instead I am using a while loop and ensuring I am going through the list only till the max of list

#5: I am looping the Quiz function until the user decides to stop playing. To start with, I am setting the flag as `yes` and checking for it before I call Quiz function. I am returning the user's decision back as a return statement. That is helping the loop to keep going.

#6: Finally, I moved all the questions outside and made `Questions` a global variable. Since we are going to call Quiz a few times, I didn't want `Questions` to be defined every time. If you want to keep it inside, its your choice. It does not impact the overall solution. However, you need to make it a list of tuples. Additionally, `inc_questions` has to be global so you can manipulate it as many times as you need.

Below is the code. Let me know if you find any errors.

```
def intro():    
    print("Hello and welcome to the random questions test")
    global name   
    name = input("what is your name? " + "\n" + "\n")
    if name == "":
        print("Enter a valid name!")
        name = input("what is your name? " + "\n" + "\n")
    else:
        ans2 = input("\n" + "Hello " + name + " Are you sure you want to take the exam? (yes/no)"  + "\n" + "\n")
        if ans2.lower() == "no":
            print("\n" + "aw man, until next time " + name + "!" + "\n")   
        elif ans2.lower() == "yes":
            print("\n" + "Okay!" + "\n")
            ans3 = 'yes'
            while ans3.lower() == 'yes':
                ans3 = Quiz()

def Quiz():
    score = 15 - len(inc_questions)
    i = 0
    while i < len(inc_questions):
        x = inc_questions[i]
        print(Questions[x][0])
        ans = input("> ")
        if ans.lower() == Questions[x][1]:
            print("\n" + "Correct!" + "\n")
            score += 1
            inc_questions.pop(i)
        else:
            print("\n" + "Incorrect!" + "\n")
            i +=1
   
    if score == 15: 
        print("Congratulations " + name + ", you scored a perfect 15/15!")
    elif score < 15 and score > 11:
        print("Good job " + name + "! you got " + str(score) + " out of 15 correct!")
    elif score < 12 and score > 8:
        print("You did pretty well " + name + ", you got " + str(score) + " out of 15 correct!")
    elif score < 9 and score > 5:
        print("Unfortunately " + name + " you did not pass, you got " + str(score) + " out of 15 correct!")
    elif score < 6 and score > 0:
        print("Jeez " + name + " you did awful lol, you got " + str(score) + " out of 15 correct!")
    elif score == 0:
        print("Oh lord " + name +" you need some serious help you got nothing right!")

    if score == 0:
        print("\n" + "Would you like a retake?" + "\n")
        ans1 = input("> ")
    elif score < 15:
        print("\n" + "Would you like to retake the questions that were incorrect?" + "\n")
        ans1 = input("> ")
    else: ans1 = ''
    
    return ans1

q1 = """Who holds the NFL record for the most receiving yards in a single game?
        a.  Calvin Johnson
        b.  Deandre Hopkins
        c.  Flipper Anderson
        d.  Jerry Rice"""
q2 = """In what year was the eiffel tower built?
        a.  1492
        b.  1889
        c.  2013
        d.  1766"""
q3 = """How many countries are in the world today?
        a.  205
        b.  195
        c.  673
        d.  142"""
q4 = """Who is the CEO of apple currently (2020)?
        a.  Tim Cook
        b.  Sergio Kitchens
        c.  Daniel Johnson
        d.  Steve Jobs"""
q5 = """who is the 23rd president of the united states?
        a.  Grover Cleveland 
        b.  Andrew Jackson
        c.  Anderson Berkshire
        d.  Benjamin Harrison"""
q6 = """X + 5x - 10 = 500... What does X equal?
        a.  85
        b.  84
        c.  102
        d.  0"""
q7 = """Who is currently the richest person on earth?
        a.  Tim Cook
        b.  Jeff Bezos
        c.  Bill Gates
        d.  Bill Nye"""
q8 = """When was Howard University Established?
        a.  May 4, 2002
        b.  March 5, 1855
        c.  September 1, 1844
        d.  March 2, 1867"""
q9 = """What can you catch but not throw?
        a.  A football
        b.  A conversation
        c.  A cold
        d.  A tennis ball in the Appalachian Mountains"""
q10 = """Which country is responsible for the production of 95% of the worlds opal stones?
        a.  Brazil 
        b.  Mexico
        c.  Honduras
        d.  Austrailia"""
q11 = """How many species of Toothed and Baleen whales exist?
        a.  14 and 2
        b.  76 and 14
        c.  5 and 10
        d.  75,000"""
q12 = """Who holds the world record for the most chicken nuggets eaten in 1 hour?
        a.  Naader Reda
        b.  Nicolo Reda
        c.  Stefano Neder
        d.  Josh Jacobs"""
q13 = """Who invented the bessemer process?
        a.  Henry Bessemer 
        b.  Markus Bessemer
        c.  Bessemer Robinson
        d.  Anakin Skywalker"""
q14 = """When was Mortal Kombat 6 released?
        a.  April 1, 2002
        b.  August 15, 2007
        c.  October 4, 2004
        d.  December 25, 2006"""
q15 = """In which City located in the USA is it illegal to say "Oh, boy"?
        a.  Denver, Colorado  
        b.  Lexington, Kentucky
        c.  Jonesboro, Georgia
        d.  Wilbur, Washington"""

Questions = [(q1,'c'),  (q2,'b'),  (q3,'b'), (q4,'a'),  (q5,'d'),  (q6,'a'),
             (q7,'b'),  (q8,'d'),  (q9,'c'), (q10,'d'), (q11,'b'), (q12,'a'),
             (q13,'a'), (q14,'c'), (q15,'c')]

inc_questions = [i for i in range(15)]

intro()
```

Here's the output part that goes back to the questions again.

I got the following questions wrong: index value of [0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14]

Here's the 15th question. Then it goes and asks the 1st and 4th question.

```
In which City located in the USA is it illegal to say "Oh, boy"?
        a.  Denver, Colorado  
        b.  Lexington, Kentucky
        c.  Jonesboro, Georgia
        d.  Wilbur, Washington
> a

Incorrect!

Jeez Joe you did awful lol, you got 5 out of 15 correct!

Would you like to retake the questions that were incorrect?

> yes
Who holds the NFL record for the most receiving yards in a single game?
        a.  Calvin Johnson
        b.  Deandre Hopkins
        c.  Flipper Anderson
        d.  Jerry Rice
> a

Incorrect!

Who is the CEO of apple currently (2020)?
        a.  Tim Cook
        b.  Sergio Kitchens
        c.  Daniel Johnson
        d.  Steve Jobs
> a

Correct!

who is the 23rd president of the united states?
        a.  Grover Cleveland 
        b.  Andrew Jackson
        c.  Anderson Berkshire
        d.  Benjamin Harrison
> a

Incorrect!

Who is currently the richest person on earth?
        a.  Tim Cook
        b.  Jeff Bezos
        c.  Bill Gates
        d.  Bill Nye
>
```

Then it goes back and asks again. From the previous round, my 15th question was incorrect. So its asking that final question again.

```
When was Mortal Kombat 6 released?
        a.  April 1, 2002
        b.  August 15, 2007
        c.  October 4, 2004
        d.  December 25, 2006
> c

Correct!

In which City located in the USA is it illegal to say "Oh, boy"?
        a.  Denver, Colorado  
        b.  Lexington, Kentucky
        c.  Jonesboro, Georgia
        d.  Wilbur, Washington
> b

Incorrect!

You did pretty well Joe, you got 10 out of 15 correct!

Would you like to retake the questions that were incorrect?

> no
>>>
```

I missed these questions again [0, 4, 7, 12, 14]. This time around, I said `no` and the program ended.

Comment: fixed minor edits. The updated code works. Please use this version.

Comment: if this solved your question, dont forget to upvote. Thanks.